# Trigger isn't working / fired while multi-row inserting

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've two tables in the DB called `KistStatus` and `LastKistStatus`. The latter will hold all the 'newest' values of `KistStatus`.

`KistStatus` has around 174.000 records, `LastKistStatus` should have around 9.500 records.

If I insert the records by hand (execute the insert one by one by hand), the `LastKistStatus` will be filled properly. But If I execute the sql export file, the trigger seems to be broken.

The trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `KistStatusTrigger`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `KistStatusTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `KistStatus`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
       DECLARE id_exists Boolean;
       DECLARE time_exists Timestamp;

       -- Check LastKistStatus table
       SELECT 1, `Timestamp`
         INTO @id_exists, @time_exists
       FROM LastKistStatus
       WHERE LastKistStatus.idKist = NEW.idKist;

       IF @id_exists > 0
       THEN
            IF @time_exists <= NEW.Timestamp
            THEN
                UPDATE LastKistStatus SET `Timestamp` = NEW.Timestamp, `idPartij` = NEW.idPartij, `Actie` = NEW.Actie, `idTaak` = NEW.idTaak, `idBewaarplaats` = NEW.idBewaarplaats, `Rij` = NEW.Rij, `Stapel` = NEW.Stapel, `Hoogte`= NEW.Hoogte, `KnolAantal` = NEW.KnolAantal, `Gewicht` = NEW.Gewicht, `idGebruiker` = NEW.idGebruiker, `Laatste` = NEW.Laatste WHERE `idKist` = NEW.idKist;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO LastKistStatus (`idKistStatus`, `idKist`, `Timestamp`, `idPartij`, `Actie`, `idTaak`, `idBewaarplaats`, `Rij`, `Stapel`, `Hoogte`, `KnolAantal`, `Gewicht`, `idGebruiker`, `Laatste` ) VALUES (NEW.idKistStatus, NEW.idKist, NEW.Timestamp, NEW.idPartij, NEW.Actie, NEW.idTaak, NEW.idBewaarplaats, NEW.Rij, NEW.Stapel, NEW.Hoogte, NEW.KnolAantal, NEW.Gewicht, NEW.idGebruiker, NEW.Laatste);
        END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Insert command (done from command line)
`mysql -u *** -p TTTDB < KistStatus.sql`

And the `KistStatus.sql` have a lot of lines like this:

```
INSERT INTO `KistStatus` (`idKistStatus`, `idKist`, `Timestamp`, `idPartij`, `Actie`, `idTaak`, `idBewaarplaats`, `Rij`, `Stapel`, `Hoogte`, `KnolAantal`, `Gewicht`, `idGebruiker`, `Laatste`) VALUES
(1, 227862, '2015-09-04 14:15:29', 40, '3', 0, 260, 2060, 33980, 1, NULL, 0, 40, 1),
(21, 229522, '2015-09-04 14:15:29', 40, '3', 0, 260, 2060, 33980, 2, NULL, 0, 40, 1),
(1083, 51102, '2015-09-05 07:33:37', 80, '3', 0, 40, 440, 5060, 1, NULL, 0, 100, 1),
(1103, 51102, '2015-09-05 07:33:44', 80, '3', 0, 40, 440, 5060, 1, NULL, 0, 100, 2),
(1123, 51102, '2015-09-05 07:33:44', 80, '3', 0, 40, 440, 5060, 1, NULL, 0, 100, 1),
(1143, 22202, '2015-09-05 07:37:33', 80, '3', 0, 40, 420, 4820, 1, NULL, 0, 100, 1);
```

I also have tested it with and insert per record, but that didn't changed anything (other than taking forever to insert...)

Sow what am I doing wrong? Is there a problem in my trigger? Wouldn't it be triggered properly while inserting it from the command line? I'm out of ideas at the moment

Comment: So you're inserting a database dump in an empty database, right? If you open your .sql file, where's the trigger defined? After both tables are defined and populated, right? :)

Comment: @Mjh I see where you're going. Right now i'm emptying the tables before executing the  `KistStatus.sql` file. And I've also executed the `DROP TRIGGER && CREATE NEW` command several times directly before firing the command line. So the trigger exist before executing all the inserts. But good catch anyways, because I found that little bug midway trough debugging

Comment: Is the problem solved now or is it still there?

Comment: @Mjh Still there.If I execute all the inserts one by one it works. But do it in 'Bulk' will result in a failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Your Problem

MySQL, somewhat confusingly, has two different types of variable:

- **local variables** (*not prefixed* by `@`), which are strongly typed and scoped to the stored program block in which they have been declared with a [`DECLARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/declare.html) statement; and
- [**user variables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) (*prefixed* by `@`), which are loosely typed and scoped to the session.  Note that they neither need nor can be declared—they are just used directly.

You declare **local variables** named `id_exists` and `time_exists`, but thereafter use **user variables** named `@id_exists` and `@time_exists`.  Since the latter are scoped to the session, they *retain their values* between subsequent invocations of the trigger within the same session—and, consequently, once `@id_exists` has been set to `1` no further records will be inserted.

The obvious solution is not to use user variables in this case, but instead to stick with your local variables: i.e. remove the `@` prefixes throughout your trigger.

## Better Approaches

1. #### Reduce data duplication

   Unless you *really* need to, don't store a copy of every column from `KistStatus` in `LastKistStatus`—you can simply store `(idKist, idKistStatus)` and fetch the underlying record as/when required.

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE LastKistStatus
     DROP COLUMN Timestamp,
     DROP COLUMN idPartij,
     DROP COLUMN Actie,
     DROP COLUMN idTaak,
     DROP COLUMN idBewaarplaats,
     DROP COLUMN Rij,
     DROP COLUMN Stapel,
     DROP COLUMN Hoogte,
     DROP COLUMN KnolAantal,
     DROP COLUMN Gewicht,
     DROP COLUMN idGebruiker,
     DROP COLUMN Laatste;
   ```

   Then, whenever you referenced `LastKistStatus` before, you can now simply reference `LastKistStatus NATURAL JOIN KistStatus` in its place and get the same results.
2. #### Learn about [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

   Given the logic in your trigger, it would appear that `LastKistStatus` will only ever contain a single record with any given `idKist`.  By enforcing this constraint in the database, you can do some clever stuff:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE LastKistStatus ADD UNIQUE KEY (idKist);
   ```

   Here I'm adding a `UNIQUE KEY` to the table.  However, it's quite probable that this could (and should) be the table's `PRIMARY KEY` instead, which has the same behaviour (but is a bit faster, given its special status).

   Now, instead of testing whether a record already exists and then inserting or updating accordingly, you can combine the operations into one:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO LastKistStatus
     (idKist, idKistStatus)
   VALUES
     (NEW.idKist, NEW.idKistStatus)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
     idKistStatus = NEW.idKistStatus;
   ```
3. #### Observe that `LastKistStatus` is really just a property of `Kist`

   I presume you have a table `Kist`.  You could simply move `idKistStatus` from the `LastKistStatus` table into that one, and do away with the `LastKistStatus` table altogether.

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE Kist
     ADD COLUMN idKistStatus BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
     ADD FOREIGN KEY (idKistStatus) REFERENCES KistStatus (idKistStatus);

   UPDATE Kist JOIN LastKistStatus USING (idKist)
   SET    Kist.idKistStatus = LastKistStatus.idKistStatus;
   ```
4. #### Do away with the trigger and cache altogether

   By finding the [groupwise maximum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) from the `KistStatus` table, you can locate the most recent status without maintaining `LastKistStatus` at all:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM KistStatus NATURAL JOIN (
     SELECT idKist, MAX(Timestamp) AS Timestamp FROM KistStatus GROUP BY idKist
   ) t;
   ```

   This would be sargable with an index over `(idKist, Timestamp)`:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE KistStatus ADD INDEX (idKist, Timestamp);
   ```

   However, notice that it will return all records from each group that have the maximal timestamp—should you have a preference for one in particular, you will need to define the logic for identifying which.

   You can even create a view to yield the same results as you used to obtain from `LastKistStatus`:

   ```sql
   CREATE VIEW LastKistStatus AS
   SELECT * FROM KistStatus NATURAL JOIN (
     SELECT idKist, MAX(Timestamp) AS Timestamp FROM KistStatus GROUP BY idKist
   ) t;
   ```

   Then use it as before:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM LastKistStatus WHERE ...
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The `@` was indeed the problem and it's working now. - About your other solutions, they sound great and we used some of the even. The problem that we where facing was that when we where loading the view (a select on the LastKistStatus), it took `1.4` seconds. While the 'static' solution with the trigger will only take `0.1` second to load...

Comment: But then again, thank you very much for your knowledgeable answer onto this topic. I'm sure it will help somebody in the future for sure

Comment: @Mathlight: Did you define the index I suggested?

Comment: Yeah. We had and have an index on the `idKist` and on the `Timestamp` columns.

Comment: @Mathlight: Just to be clear, a composite index across both columns (and in the order I suggested) is not the same as separate indexes across the individual columns nor even a composite across the same columns in a different order.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out... Seemed like the index was indeed set wrong (individual instead of composite). Thank you for taking the time to explain ;-)